# PHP and Javascript working together

Tags: php, javascript, real-time

It may sound odd, but I've been programming games in PHP. The main problem I've found was that the only way to update PHP is to load a page. That makes real-time slow. Javascript can interact with a page without reloading it. Is it possible to load PHP pages on a page using Javascript? So that it would allow PHP to be loaded over and over without reloading.

I've seen it done with Chat rooms but not sure how it works.

Comment: Yes, ajax. And if you are doing ajax I would highly recomend the jquery library as it makes it much easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We mostly use Ajax, which consists in a client-side Javascript code that calls a server-side page, with out leaving the page.

Here's an example that will get the displayed content of a page, using the **GET** method ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MPNm/)):

```
var xhr = XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHttp');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState==4 && ((xhr.status>=200 && xhr.status<300) || xhr.status==304)){//Checks if the content was loaded
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET','myPHPPage.php?foo=foo&bar=bar',true);
xhr.send();
```

And here using the **POST** method ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy4c3/)):

```
var xhr = XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHttp');
var data = 'foo=foo&bar=bar';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState==4 && ((xhr.status>=200 && xhr.status<300) || xhr.status==304)){//Checks if the content was loaded
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open('POST','myPHPPage.php',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-length',data.length);
xhr.send(data);
```

Note that here we use the `setRequestHeader` method to change the headers of this HTTP request and, in this case, to change the `Content-type` and the `Content-length` (this header has a default value of 4096 bytes). Also, the `setRequestHeader` method **must** be called after the `open` method.

These links should help you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Ajax

http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's incredibly common. 
Read up on Ajax.

Comment: Is that what Facebook uses to pop new statuses up without having to update page?

Comment: I read on w3schools like Abadis suggested before. I see its short. Is there more and/or better place to learn about Ajax or is that pretty much it? Btw, thanks, this makes a lot more sense.

Comment: See my answer, there are some links

Comment: Also, while using Ajax, should I use POST or GET? I'm going to being data to a database that could be long and should be secure.

Comment: So in this case POST is the better solution

Comment: I've seen that GET is faster though? Would the speed really affect it?

Comment: Worry about the performance of the tool *after* you've learned to use the tool :)

Answer (score 0):

We call that AJAX!!!
Just Read The documentation on internet about ajax

Comment: Take care: People here don't like w3schools.com

Comment: While linking to w3schools can be okey, calling it 'the documentation' is plain wrong.